# Selenium not opening the browser and the code instead runs in JAVA console and throws error message

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
package firstSeleniumTesting;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class testingAutomation {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.drive", "C:\\SeleniumDriver\\chromedriver_win32");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); //Launches Firefox
    driver.close();
    
}

}
```

I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require$StateChecker.nonNull(Require.java:280)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:434)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:46)
    at firstSeleniumTesting.testingAutomation.main(testingAutomation.java:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the **.exe** in the chromedriver

Use like this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumDriver\\chromedriver_win32.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
    driver.close();
```

Comment: also fix the typo: "webdriver.chrome.drive"... should be: ""webdriver.chrome.driver"